# Tainted_source JAVA

Tags: java, http, service, request, coverity

I analyzed the code of some services in java with Coverity and they throw the following security problems in the controller: "tainted_source: entering this function as a framework entry point. parameter bodyparams is tainted because it comes from an http request." What is the correct way to deal with this type of parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output shown in your question is only one portion of the complete finding.  It shows why `service_id` is considered to be "tainted" (i.e., under potential control of an attacker), but does not show what happens to the tainted data, and hence we can't know what the code is trying to do or how to fix it.

In the Coverity GUI there is an "events panel" in the lower-right corner that can be used to navigate to the rest of the finding.  By clicking on the events in that panel you should be able to see what happens to `service_id`, and there is sometimes a recommendation from the tool about how to fix it.

Disclosure: I used to work for Coverity/Synopsys.

Comment: hi @scott-mcpeak, I am getting similar error. The parameter obtained over http is used further to construct a unix command. And that is marked as os_command_sink. Can you please provide some guidance how to mark the parameter untainted? thanks.

Comment: @Eager I suggest asking a new question with a complete code example and the Coverity finding.  That will enable a more complete and accurate answer than is possible in a comment, and will let others benefit from the question and its answer.

Comment: thanks I have asked a new question with more details in it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510258/tainted-source-os-command-sink