# TAINTED_SOURCE - os_command_sink

Tags: java, rest, coverity

Further to [Tainted_source JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62141072/tainted-source-java), I want to add more information regarding the error os_command_sink I am getting.

Below is the section of code that's entry point of data from front end and marks parameter as tainted_souce

[image]

Now when the DTO - CssEmailWithAttachment is sent to static method of CommandUtils, it reports os_command_sink issue. Below is the code for the method

[image]

I tried various ways to sanitize the source in controller method - referenceDataExport i.e. using allowlist, using @Pattern annotation but coverity reports os_command_sink all the times.

I understand the reason as any data coming from http is marked as tainted by default. And the code is using the data to construct an OS command hence the issue is reported.

Coverity provides below information regarding the issue
[image]

So I tried strict validation of entityType that it should be one of the known values only but that also doesn't remove the issue.

Is there anyway this can be resolved?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that the code, as it currently stands, is insecure.  To summarize the Coverity report:

1. `entityType` comes from an HTTP parameter, hence is under attacker control.
2. `entityType` is concatenated into `tagline`.
3. `tagline` is passed as the body and subject of `CdsEmailWithAttachment`.  (You haven't included the constructor of that class, so this is partially speculation on my part.)
4. The subject and body are concatenated into an `sh` command line.  Consequently, anyone who can invoke your HTTP service can execute arbitrary command lines on your server backend!

There is an attempt at validation in `sendEmailWithAttachment`, where certain shell metacharacters are filtered out.  However, the filtering is incomplete (missing at least single and double quote) and is not applied to the subject.

So, your first task here is to **fix the vulnerability**.  The Coverity tool has correctly reported that there is a problem, but making Coverity happy is not the goal, and even if it stops reporting after you make a change, that does not necessarily mean the vulnerability is fixed.

There are at least two straightforward ways I see to fix this code:

1. Use a whitelist filter on `entityType`, rejecting the request if the value is not among a fixed list of safe strings.  You mentioned trying the [`@Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation, and that could work *if used correctly*.  Be sure to test that your filter works and provides a sensible error message.
2. Instead of invoking `mailx` via `sh`, invoke it directly using [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  This way you can safely transport arbitrary data into `mailx` without the risks of a shell command line.

Personally, I would do both of these.  It appears that `entityType` is meant to be one of a fixed set of values, so should be validated regardless of any vulnerability potential; and using `sh` is both risky from a security perspective and makes controlling the underlying process difficult (e.g., implementing a timeout).

Whatever you decide to do, **test the fix**.  In fact, I recommend first (before changing the code) demonstrating that the code is vulnerable by constructing an exploit, as that will be needed later to test any fix, and is a valuable exercise in its own right.  When you think you have fixed the problem, write more tests to really be sure.  Think like an attacker; be devious!

Finally, I suspect you may be inexperienced at dealing with potential security vulnerabilities (I apologize if I'm mistaken).  If so, please understand that code security is very important, and getting it right is difficult.  If you have the option, I recommend consulting with someone in your organization who has more experience with this topic.  Do **not** rely only on Coverity.